# How to correctly encode html tags for posting, using a <form>

Tags: php, html, forms, post

**Question: What is the correct way to post HTML code using a POST form?**

I have created a form that takes in HTML code as its input in a `textarea`

```
 <form action="create_html_document.php" method="POST">
    <textarea name="provided_html"></textarea>
    <input type="submit" value="Create">
 </form>
```

The posted HTML code is losing all of its opening tags when `var_dump`ed in the `create_html_document.php` script.

Note, I am filtering input using the below line, but it still happens if I omit the line:

`$_POST  = filter_input_array(INPUT_POST, FILTER_SANITIZE_STRING);`

When I `var_dump($_POST['provided_html']);` in the `create_html_document.php` file, I notice all the **opening** HTML tags are now missing and replaced with `\r` or `\n`, but the content inside them is still there, so are the closing tags.

**Here is an example of an input I have tried:**

```
<!doctype html>
<html>
  <head>
  </head>
  <body>
    Hello Everyone
  </body>
</html>
```

**This becomes**

`"\r\n\r\n \r\n <\/head>\r\n \r\n Hello Everyone\r\n <\/body>\r\n<\/html>\r\n"`

Do I need to encode the html code before it is posted, then decode before saving it to my back end? Or maybe there is a special form type I do not know about, which will do it automatically. So this poses the question:

**How do I effectively post HTML code by using a form, without losing the tags?**

Comment: _“Clearly I need to encode the html code before it is posted”_ - no; you always need to handle data according to the rules of the specific context, when you put it _into_ that context. The context here is HTML, so you need to apply an appropriate escaping function the moment you put it into that context. `var_dump(htmlspecialchars($_POST['provided_html']));` (And using `FILTER_SANITIZE_STRING` makes little sense, if you _want_ to send HTML code here, the purpose of that is to _remove_ “tags”.)

Comment: Why the minus 1? I could use feedback if there's something wrong with the question

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you are using PHP to host the html, [maybe this helps?](https://www.php.net/htmlspecialchars) It says you can use htmlspacialchars() like this:

```
htmlspecialchars ( string $string [, int $flags = ENT_COMPAT | ENT_HTML401 [, string $encoding = ini_get("default_charset") [, bool $double_encode = TRUE ]]] ) : string
```